# Javascript function immediately invoking

Tags: javascript, function, invoke

I have two js files. First one  (alert.js)

```
function test() {
    var name= document.getElementById("name").value; 
    alert(name);
};
```

and second one  (main.js)

```
document.getElementById("question_button").addEventListener("click", test());
```

in html i looks like that

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/alert.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Function test is invoked when page is loaded. It's not what I need. It's probably very simple but I dont get it. How to make function "test" invoke only when button is pressed?

Comment: Change `test()` to `test`

Comment: `test()` invokes the function, you want just `test` in your `addEventListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `test()` and passing the value it returns ( `undefined` ) to `addEventListener`. Just pass `test` directly as an argument instead of calling it:

```
document.getElementById("question_button").addEventListener("click", test);
```

or pass in an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById("question_button").addEventListener("click", function ( ) { test(x) } );
```

Comment: Ok it works fine. But what if i need to call function "test" with an argument? 
Say "test" looks like that: 
`function test(val) {
    alert(val);
};`

And the second part of the code looks like that:
`var x = "alert x!";

document.getElementById("question_button").addEventListener("click", test(x));`

How to fix it in this case?

Comment: You could use an anonymous function.  Look at the following [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Event_Listener_with_anonymous_function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Event_Listener_with_anonymous_function).

Comment: @Bajzel One way is to pass an anonymous function that calls `test(x)`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome. That's all i need! Thanks